# neo4j Regex encoding yielding puzzling results

Tags: regex, neo4j

Am encountering some really really weird stuff using regex matches.

```
MATCH (n:Node) 
RETURN id(n), n.Property
```

Results: 3  "1 "

```
MATCH (n:Node) WHERE id(n)=3 AND n.Property="1 " RETURN n.Property
```

No changes no records

```
MATCH (n:Node) WHERE id(n)=3 AND trim(n.Property)="1 " RETURN n.Property
```

No changes no records

```
MATCH (n:Node) 
WHERE id(n)=3 
AND replace(replace(replace(replace(i.Property, "\t", ""), "\r", ""), "\f", ""), "\n", "")="1 "
RETURN n.Property
```

No changes no records

It won't let me replace /s or /h without giving an error.

When I use regex, same issue.

```
MATCH (n:Node) 
WHERE id(n)=3 
RETURN CASE WHEN n.Property=~"1" THEN true ELSE false END AS bool
```

yields false

```
MATCH (n:Node) 
WHERE id(n)=3 RETURN CASE WHEN n.Property=~"1 " THEN true ELSE false END AS bool
```

yields false

```
MATCH (n:Node) 
WHERE id(n)=3 RETURN CASE WHEN n.Property=~"(?u)1 " THEN true ELSE false END AS bool
```

yields false

All of these return false
"(?u)\u0009"
"(?u)\u000A"
"(?u)\u000B"
"(?u)\u000C"
"(?u)\u000D"
"(?u)\u0085"
"(?u)\u0020"
"(?u)\u00A0"
"(?u)\u1680"
"(?u)\u180E"
"(?u)\u2000"
"(?u)\u2001"
"(?u)\u2002"
"(?u)\u2003"
"(?u)\u2004"
"(?u)\u2005"
"(?u)\u2006"
"(?u)\u2007"
"(?u)\u2008"
"(?u)\u2009"
"(?u)\u2028"
"(?u)\u2029"
"(?u)\u200A"
"(?u)\u200B"
"(?u)\u202F"
"(?u)\u205F"
"(?u)\u3000"
"(?u)\uFEFF"

```
MATCH (n:Node) 
WHERE id(n)=3 RETURN CASE WHEN n.Property=~"1.*" THEN true ELSE false END AS bool
```

yields true

```
MATCH (n:Node)
WHERE id(n)=3 RETURN CASE WHEN n.Property=~"(?u)\u0031.*" THEN true ELSE false END AS bool
```

yields true

How can I figure out what that space character is since I can't seem to copy it? I have noticed same issue sometimes when there is a different unicode in the string - it looks like one I know but when I look for all its versions it does not match. Is there a way to ask Neo4j to spit out the encoding it's using for that particular property?

Comment: Have you tried exporting the results as CSV and inspecting the results in a text editor?

Comment: use right trim rTrim to remove space(s) on the right.  For example: RETURN rTrim('hello   ')

Comment: Thanks guys - I did try both those things and it just comes up as a space. However, I redid all the options and I must have messed up because this comes back true: 
match (i:Node) where id(i)=3 RETURN CASE WHEN i.Property=~"1(?u)\u00A0" THEN true ELSE false END AS bool

So it's \u00A0. But man, there's got to be a better way!!